# Why don't loops scale evenly?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I do not believe this to be a duplicate, I've looked for it, but really had no clue what to call it exactly.

I want to know why a loop that is ten times larger than another loop doesn't take ten times longer to run.

I was doing some testing to try and figure out how to make my website faster and more reactive, so I was using `microtime()` before and after functions. On my website, I'm not sure how to pull lists of table rows with certain attributes out without going through the entire table, and I wanted to know if this was what was slowing me down.

So using the following loop:

```
echo microtime(), "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "") or die(mysqli_connection_error());; 
echo microtime(), "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
$x=1000;
$messagequery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='$x'");
while(!$messagequery or mysqli_num_rows($messagequery) == 0) {
    echo('a');
    $x--;
    $messagequery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='$x'");
    }
echo "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
```

I got the following output and similar outputs:

```
0.14463300 1376367329
0.14464400 1376367329
0.15548900 1376367330
0.15550000 1376367330 < these two
[a's omitted, for readability]
0.33229800 1376367330 < these two
0.33230700 1376367330
```

~18-20 microseconds, not that bad, nobody will notice that. So I wondered what would happen as my website grew. What would happen if I had 10 times as many (10,000) table rows to search through?

```
0.11086600 1376367692
0.11087600 1376367692
0.11582100 1376367693
0.11583600 1376367693
[lots of a's]
0.96294500 1376367694
0.96295500 1376367694
```

~83-88 microseconds. Why isn't it 180-200 microseconds? Does it take time to start and stop a loop or something?

**UPDATE:** To see if it was the mySQL adding variables, I tested it without the mySQL:

```
echo microtime(), "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "W2072a", "triiline1") or die(mysqli_connection_error());; 
echo microtime(), "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
$x=1000000;
while($x > 10) {
    echo('a');
    $x--;
    }
echo "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
echo microtime(), "<br>";
```

Now it appears that at one million, it takes ~100 milliseconds(right?) and at ten million it takes ~480 milliseconds. So, my question still stands. Why do larger loops move more quickly? It's not important, I'm not planning my entire website design based off of this, but I am interested.

Comment: Re-check your units. Those time deltas are *milliseconds*. (`0.332298 sec - 0.155500 sec = 0.176798 sec = 176.798 milliseconds`)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the loop directly.  You're querying MySQL.  There are 100s of factors.

Comment: if your running the same query then its cached on `query cache` doesn't even hit the disk for i/o

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure. The manual says:
"msec is the number of microseconds that have elapsed since sec expressed in seconds."

Either way, it's a tiny amount of time.

Comment: Use `microtime(TRUE)` to get the result in seconds as a single float value. And also, yes, I definitely wouldn't worry about variances on the order of 10s of milliseconds when dealing with a webserver and database.

Comment: Cache misses. Has to be a cache miss (except for the MySQL piece)

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson don't you mean cache hits?
Anyway, I think although it doesn't look much, "echo('a')" is probably the main factor because buffering stops i/o from growing as fast as the number of iterations.

Comment: @imel96 Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, loops will scale linearly.

Possible bug: If you haven't already done so, consider what might happen if there was no record with id 900.

I would strongly recommend using MySQL to do your filtration work for you via WHERE clauses rather than sorting thru information this way.  It's not really scalable.

Frankly, the line

> while(!$messagequery or mysqli_num_rows($messagequery) == 0) {

doesn't make sense to me.  `$messagequery` will be false if a failure occurs, and you want the loop to run as long as `mysqli_num_rows($messagequery)` is NOT equal to zero, I think.  However, that's not what the above code does.

If `mysqli_num_rows($messagequery)` is equal to zero, the loop will continue.

If `mysqli_num_rows($messagequery)` is NOT equal to zero, the loop will stop.

See operator precedence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Does that help answer your question?

Comment: You answered my question and more! I use loops similar to this one to pull products and messages out of a database, and on the products for example, I pull out the products by product ID, put the info into a template, and display it, and then repeat, while doing this x times per page. I've been wondering how to order them by price or date added, but I've been putting that off. How would I use WHERE clauses to do this faster, I don't quite understand?

Comment: You can use SQL statements to return groups of rows based upon a filtration metric.  E.G.: if you want all records with IDs in the range 10-100, you can write `$messagequery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID >= 10 AND ID <= 100");`, which will return 91 records, which can be iterated with another loop.  The flexibility of MySQL filtration is much more powerful; that is only a basic example.  However, that's a new question altogether.  This might help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Comment: Never realized I could do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are really interested in this, you might take a look at the op codes that PHP creates. The [Vulcan Logic Disassembler (VLD)](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld) might help you with this.

However, this shouldn't be your problem if you are only interested in your site speed. You won't have speed benefits/drawbacks just because of the loops themselves, but on the things they actually loop on (MySQL queries, arrays, ...).

Compare this small test script:

```
<pre>
<?php

$small_loop = 3000;
$big_loop = $small_loop*$small_loop;
$start = microtime(true);

// Big loop
for ($i = 0; $i < $big_loop; $i++) {
    ; // do nothing
}
echo "Big loop took " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds\n";

$start = microtime(true);
// Small loops
for ($i = 0; $i < $small_loop; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $small_loop; $j++) {
        ;
    }
}
echo"Small loops took " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds\n";
?>
</pre>
```

The output for me was:

```
Big loop took 0.59838700294495 seconds
Small loops took 0.592453956604 seconds
```

As you can see the difference in 1 loop vs. 3000 loops isn't really significant.